# Group Policy Startup Script Not Working

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, startup-scripts

I have a startup script on my server that is suppose to run at startup and install Office 2010 on my workstation computer however it is not working. Running rsop.msc it shows that the startup script is being called on the workstation computer.

The server has Windows 2008 R2 and the workstation has Windows 7

Here is the script: http://pastebin.com/c03gvvbt

I have followed the directions on: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602181.aspx

The workstation has access to the folder so I'm not sure why this script is not running, any ideas?

Comment: have your tried running the script while logged in, just to confirm it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To troubleshoot it, I would reccomend the following:

1. Try running logged in as your self, just to confirm it works.
2. Create a test GPO and setup this script in there.  Then move a test system in there.  In the GPO enable your script as you were, but also set the logon scripts to be visable and to run syncronous.  Secondly, put a pause statement in your script so you can check for errors.
3. If you haven't done so already, also check your app log to see if there's any errors with the install its self.